# using javascript instead of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I find that using Javascript's OOP approach is easier when building a site because it allows for easier organization of objects. Jquery comes in handy if effects need to be applied, but if not, I find Javascript objects easier to get the job done with. Has anyone else had similar experience? Does anyone disagree?

Comment: Discussion question. Doesn't belong here. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: Why would you think OOP and jQuery are mutually exclusive? jQuery is just a library, not a language. If you use jQuery, you are using javascript.

Comment: I think that you don't knwo jQuery, that is best JS library ever, and it really simplify your developer life.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jquery is javascript, so I would disagree.

Answer (score 1):

The only exclusivity between the two is the mental models you get trapped in as a developer.  JQuery is borne out of DOM search / manipulation.  It's brilliance, ubiquity, and extensibility have led people to write plugins that leverage JQuery to do tons of stuff unrelated to the original problem, and it's incredibly convenient to use these.

The conflict I think you're having is that using JQuery elevates DOM $(elements) to the primary, and for some developers only, object that javascript manipulates.  In many web applications you need an independent javascript data model which sometimes interacts with the DOM.  Read up on Backbone, Knockout, and MVC / MVVM design patterns if you want to get into this discussion seriously.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is a javascript library so if you write plain 'ol javascript to do something found in jQuery, you're reinventing the wheel. You can definitely use additional javascript in addition to jQuery where it's needed but there's rarely a good reason to ignore jQuery in favor of writing the javascript code from scratch.